# angular ui.boostrap popup datepicker date-disabled not working

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, ui.bootstrap

This is my first angular js site so please excuse my ignorance.

I've added a `ui.boostrap` popup datepicker to my page which works perfectly except it appears the dateDisabled method never gets hit.

My markup looks like the following:

```
<input id="inputWeekEnding"
       type="text"
       class="form-control"
       uib-datepicker-popup="mediumDate"
       ng-model="vm.weekEnding"
       is-open="vm.weekEndingOpen.opened"
       ng-required="true"
       close-text="Close"
       date-options="vm.dateOptions"
       ng-change="vm.weekEndingChanged()"/>
```

and my controller:

```
vm.dateOptions = {
        dateDisabled: function (data) {
            var date = data.date,
                mode = data.mode;
            return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() !== 0));
        }
    };
```

I've even tried hardcoding the return true and still no dates are disabled.  I've seen this work on a variety of different plunkers so I know it works.  As mentioned my `dateDisabled` function never gets hit.  I'm assuming it's ok as other methods of the calender get hit such as `vm.weekEndingOpen.opened` and `vm.weekEndingChanged()`.

I'm wondering whether I've forgotten to add a script file.  My scripts look like the following:

```
    <!-- Library Scripts -->
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

While I'm asking a datepicker question, I've noticed on other peoples plunkers that their date pickers look a little better, like the calendar has more shadows, perhaps it's the version I'm using.  Also my days of the week are not showing, they're there but they don't show as I have a white background and the text is white.

My library versions are as follows:

```
<package id="Angular.UI.Bootstrap" version="1.3.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Animate" version="1.5.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Core" version="1.5.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Resource" version="1.5.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.6" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Not sure if this is relevant but I am getting failed gets looking for icons also:
-  http://localhost/TimeSheet.WebSite/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 
-  http://localhost/TimeSheet.WebSite/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't disabled attribute for datepicker. You should use datepicker-options:

```
<input datepicker-options="dateOptions" ... >   

 $scope.dateOptions = {
        dateDisabled: function (data) {
          var date = data.date,
          mode = data.mode;
          return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
        }
 };
```

Read the documentation: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup

Comment: Thanks @Roman, unfortunately I've tried this so I have exactly what you have and my method still doesn't get hit.

Comment: I've edited my post to what you've suggested and as per the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Roman, I got it to work just as you (and the doco) suggested.  I've marked yours as a correct answer but it won't show publically as I don't have high enough reputation yet.